# Does Max Flow produce uniform results?

Tags: graph-theory, linear-programming, flows

I am interested in using Max Flow algorithm. I want to simulate transfer of quantity. Anyway, I am unsure of some thing.

Does Max Flow algorithm produce uniformly distributed max flow?

I have provided example picture to show what I meant.

Black: edge capabilities
Red: wrong, non-uniform results
Green: correct, uniform results

[max-flow-image-example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBLQm.png)

I do realize there are many types of Max Flow algorithms, so to add onto question, or to be more specific - which Max Flow algorithms produce uniform max flow and which don't?

Extra thing: I will use floating points (converted into integers) and then back. But I don't think this matters here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Uniformly in what sense? Different edges may have different capacities.

Comment: Good point. I drew another picture.

Lets say this way:
uniform, if nothing is maxed out.
If some edge is maxed out, then remaining quantity gets distributed equally to other non-maxed edges.


Example picture:
https://imgur.com/a/gZpRka2

I do not have "maxed out edge" scenario, but I shall draw some too.

Comment: One path maxed out example pic:
https://imgur.com/a/U9cDDXz

Comment: It is a property of the problem that often the maximum is only reached on a path (with the edges outside it carrying no flow at all). That is, it's as non-uniform as it possibly could be.

Comment: Many algorithms will always produce a basic solution (in the linear programming sense), thus an extreme point of the feasible region.  This is, as Dima said, "as non-uniform as it possibly could be".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical max flow algorithms won't necessarily output a uniform flow.

The following paper defines a version of max flow called "balanced flow", and solve it in polynomial time.

Devanur, N. R., Papadimitriou, C. H., Saberi, A., & Vazirani, V. V. (2008). Market equilibrium via a primal--dual algorithm for a convex program. Journal of the ACM (JACM), 55(5), 22.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, it's feature of Max Flow to produce extreme results (or more like Linear Programming produces extreme results). So, it's not possible that Max Flow always produces uniform results.

Comment: Not being possible is a wild phrase. For example, after finding the max flow you can reduce each edge that a large amount of flow passed through it and see whether the solution changes. Or you can increase the capacities step by step from the start.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Will research those options :).